# Propper JTextArea Text Wrappping

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap

I currently use this class to put text into a 'log' `JTextArea`:

```
public void appendOutput(String output) { 
    textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "\n " + output); 
}
```

This works pretty well except for the fact that a text wrapping `JTextArea` will cut words in half. Is there a good/easy fix for this?

[image: This is what it does...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true)
```

So in your case it would be:

```
textPane.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```